# What's the difference between binding.pry and Pry.start?

Tags: ruby, debugging, scope, read-eval-print-loop, pry

```rb
require 'pry'

var = "variable"

class Gnar
    def self.gar
        @var = "lar!"
        # binding.pry
        # Pry.start(binding)
        # Pry.start
    end
end

Gnar.gar
```

When I uncomment `binding.pry`, I find myself in a Pry REPL with `self == Gnar`. When I uncomment `Pry.start(binding)`, the Pry REPL is never launched. When I uncomment `Pry.start`, I find myself in a Pry REPL with `self == main`.

I don't understand this behavior, and I want to really grasp the nitty-gritty of this essential Ruby debugging tool. I want to focus on the behavior of `binding.pry` and `Pry.start(binding)`.

In one case we're calling the `#pry` method on the `binding` object and in the other we're calling the `.start` method on the `Pry` class with `binding` as an argument.

Let's start with `binding.pry`. According to [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pry/0.10.3/Object), `#pry` is defined as follows:

```rb
def pry(object=nil, hash={})
  if object.nil? || Hash === object
    Pry.start(self, object || {})
  else
    Pry.start(object, hash)
  end
end
```

Based on that method definition, when we call `#pry` on an object with no arguments, we call `Pry.start(self, {})` where `self` is whatever `self` is in the `binding` context.

So what's going on in `Pry.start`? [The definition in the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pry/0.10.3/Pry.start) is pretty long, but what I notice is that `self` is passed in as the `target` of `Pry.start`, which is then used on this line:

```rb
options[:target] = Pry.binding_for(target || toplevel_binding) #line 152
```

before

```rb
# Enter the matrix
  driver.start(options) #line 169
```

With all of this in mind, it's my understanding that `binding.pry` results in a REPL starting via `driver.start(options)` with `options[:target] = Pry.binding_for(binding)`. **Why is `Pry.start(binding)` not exhibiting the same behavior (i.e. not launching a REPL) if `target == binding` in both cases? What incorrect assumptions am I making?** I kind of understand that `Pry.start` launches a REPL with `self == main` as the default `target == toplevel_binding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Pry.start(binding)` from within a console should have a similar effect to calling `binding.pry`:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.6.2)
[1] pry(main)> class Gnar
[1] pry(main)*   def self.gar    
[1] pry(main)*     @var = "lar!"        
[1] pry(main)*     Pry.start(binding)
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :gar
[2] pry(main)> Gnar.gar

From: /Users/redacted/.gem/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb @ line 388 Pry#evaluate_ruby:

    383: def evaluate_ruby(code)
    384:   inject_sticky_locals!
    385:   exec_hook :before_eval, code, self
    386: 
    387:   result = current_binding.eval(code, Pry.eval_path, Pry.current_line)
 => 388:   set_last_result(result, code)
    389: ensure
    390:   update_input_history(code)
    391:   exec_hook :after_eval, result, self
    392: end

[1] pry(#<Pry>)>
```

A Binding object encapsulates the execution context of your code at a specific location. `Binding#pry` starts a Pry REPL over a Binding object.

`Pry.start` just starts a Pry REPL. If you don't pass it a binding, then it's just a Pry REPL without any execution context; the console tells you whether or not it has context by changing from `pry(main)` (no context) to `pry(#<Pry>)>` if the execution context of the binding passed to it was a Pry instance:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.6.2)
[1] pry(main)> Pry.start(binding)

From: /Users/redacted/.gem/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb @ line 388 Pry#evaluate_ruby:

    383: def evaluate_ruby(code)
    384:   inject_sticky_locals!
    385:   exec_hook :before_eval, code, self
    386: 
    387:   result = current_binding.eval(code, Pry.eval_path, Pry.current_line)
 => 388:   set_last_result(result, code)
    389: ensure
    390:   update_input_history(code)
    391:   exec_hook :after_eval, result, self
    392: end

[1] pry(#<Pry>)> exit
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> binding.pry

From: /Users/redacted/.gem/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb @ line 388 Pry#evaluate_ruby:

    383: def evaluate_ruby(code)
    384:   inject_sticky_locals!
    385:   exec_hook :before_eval, code, self
    386: 
    387:   result = current_binding.eval(code, Pry.eval_path, Pry.current_line)
 => 388:   set_last_result(result, code)
    389: ensure
    390:   update_input_history(code)
    391:   exec_hook :after_eval, result, self
    392: end

[1] pry(#<Pry>)> exit
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> exit
```

Similarly, calling binding.pry from within a class method opens up a Pry REPL within the execution context of that class (`pry(ClassName)`). Calling binding.pry from within an *instance method* opens up a Pry REPL within the execution context of that *instance* (`pry(#<ClassName>`).

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.6.2)
[1] pry(main)> class A
[1] pry(main)*   def self.b
[1] pry(main)*     binding.pry
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)*   
[1] pry(main)*   def c
[1] pry(main)*     binding.pry
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :c
[2] pry(main)> A.b

From: (pry) @ line 4 A.b:

    2: def self.b
    3:   binding.pry
 => 4: end

[1] pry(A)> exit
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> A.new.c

From: (pry) @ line 8 A#c:

    6: def c
    7:   binding.pry
 => 8: end

[1] pry(#<A>)> exit
=> nil
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That makes total sense! I think I was running into some sort of bug by having `Pry.start(binding)` be the last line in the class method. When I sketched out the class today in IRB with both `binding.pry` and `Pry.start(binding)`, it behaved as you described and I expected! Thank you.